# jQuery UI Draggable not working on child element

Tags: jquery

My goal is to create a box (a `div` element) inside a larger `div` area (let's call it 'canvas' but not to be confused with HTML's canvas element) and give the user the possibility to drag them to various parts of the canvas area. Boxes can be created by clicking a link (an `<a>` tag).

I am facing two issues:

1. The first time the site loads, pressing the link does show the box for a fraction of a second but clears the canvas. I need to press the link once again for the box to appear and remain on the canvas. I added `{revert: false}` as the input to `draggable()` but didn't solve it.
2. The box(es) that appear are not draggable.

I'm not sure where I am wrong.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".dropdown-btn").click(function() {
    $(".canvas").append('<div class="indi-box"><div>Indicator</div><form><select id="dropdown"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select></form><div>');
  });
  $(".indi-box").draggable({
    revert: false
  });
});
```

```css
.canvas {
  height: 50vw;
  width: 90vw;
  background-color: powderblue;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.indi-box {
  background-color: #336DFF;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 2px;
}

#dropdown {
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-btn">Create Box</a>
  <div class="canvas"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because the element with class `indi-box` does not exist when

```js
  $(".indi-box").draggable({
    revert: false
  });
```

Try this:

```js
  $(".dropdown-btn").click(function() {
    $(".canvas").append('<div class="indi-box"><div>Indicator</div><form><select id="dropdown"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select></form><div>');
    $(".indi-box").draggable({
      revert: false
    });
  });
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you did in the second example. Did you manually add the <div><form>... part to the DOM? Besides, I tried both of your jQuery scripts but none of them worked unfortunately. Upon clicking on the link, nothing happens.

Comment: Yeah, I did. It's strange because when I run this it works, hmm...

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, if you use the first method that I suggested it should work. The second not working because element was created and `.draggable()` not worked to him

Comment: Alright, now it's all clear, that solved my issue. Also, it works fine even if there are multiple "indi-box" elements on the "canvas". Great! Thank you! :)